# Wordpress: register_activation_hook doesnt' working on my plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm creating a new plugin test and when I activate in my wordpress plugin area, nothing happens...

Does anyone has the same question?
I haven't any error messages, just nothing happens to...

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My Admin
Plugin URI: 
Description: Seu admin personalizado.
Version: 0.1.4
Author: Vinícius Lourenço
Author URI: 
Text Domain: my-admin
Domain Path: /languages
*/

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'ativar' );

function ativar(){
    add_action('admin_menu','vilourenco_create_menu');
}


function vilourenco_create_menu(){
    add_menu_page('Menu de Opções','ViLourenco Settings','administrator', 'admin_fera' , 'vilourenco_menu_page','dashicons-format-status');
    add_action('admin_init','vilourenco_register_settings');
}


function vilourenco_register_settings(){
    register_setting('vilourenco-options', 'nome');
    register_setting('vilourenco-options', 'idade');
    register_setting('vilourenco-options', 'cidade');
}

function vilourenco_menu_page(){
    ?>
<div class="wrap">
<?php screen_icon(); ?>
<h2>Vinicius Plugin</h2>

<?php if( isset( $_GET['settings-updated'] ) ) : ?>
    <div class="updated">
      <p>Configurações salvas com sucesso!</p>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields( 'vilourenco-options' ); ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections( 'vilourenco-options' ); ?>
    <table class="form-table">
    <tr valign="top">
    <th scope="row">Nome</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="nome" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('nome') ); ?>" />    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr valign="top">
    <th scope="row">Idade</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="idade" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('idade') ); ?>" />   </td>
    </tr>

    <tr valign="top">
    <th scope="row">Porte</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="cidade" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('cidade') ); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php submit_button(); ?>

</form>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: What is the content of your log ? How can you sur that the problem is coming from the code psoted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback of `register_activation_hook` is executed only once, that is on activation. It is generally used to add options, or create database tables.

Registering plugin settings and menus should be done in separate functions, hooked into (admin) init.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook

Comment: Great! Thanks @diggy!
Now I using add_action() to set this function and register_activation_hook only to specific tasks like you said.